# save answer with button radio using MEAN stack with MVC framework

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, mongoose, radio-button, mean-stack

i am setting a form with Mean Stack, 
in form.html i have

```
<div ng-controller="InfoCtrl">
 <form method="post" ng-submit="info()" name="infoForm">
<div class="radio">
       <label>
     <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="Homme" value="Homme" checked>
   Homme
 </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
<label>
<input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="Femme" value="Femme">
Femme
```

and in the controller info.js i have :

```
angular.module('MyApp')
 .controller('InfoCtrl',[ '$scope', 'infor', function($scope, infor) {
 $scope.info = function() {
    infor.info({
    age: $scope.age,
    sexe: $scope.optionsRadios
  });
};
  }]);
```

another file infor.js, it only contains the error message after the set of the form, in the class server.js i have this function:

```
 app.post('/infor/info', function(req, res, next) {
   console.log('ok');
  var query =  {'email' : 'mail@mail.fr' };

 var age1 = req.body.age;
 console.log(req.body.optionsRadios);

 User.findOneAndUpdate(query,{ age: age1 } , {upsert:true},function(err, doc){
 if (err) return res.send(500, { error: err });
 return res.send("succesfully saved");
 });
 });
```

but i didn't knew how to save the answer of the button radio in the query like i did in the set of new text. I have searched in many forms but it i didn't found an answer!

Comment: Check how radios work here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D   inputs need model attribute which is missing

Comment: with `console.log(req.body.optionsRadios);` i see in the console undefined, what is the type that i should make in the schema?

Comment: Just add ng-model="optionsRadios" to your inputs

Comment: it is always undefined variable, i have declared it in the user schema in the server.js sexe: String, should i change it?

Comment: If req.body.optionsRadios is always undefined then the problem is with POST from client. I just noticed in infor.info.... you have age and sexe so on the server check req.body.sexe

Comment: it is always the same! and in form.html i changed into this one

Comment: `<input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" name="age" ng-model="age" placeholder="Age" required>`

Comment: Did you change the radios to have ng-model too?

Comment: i have just did and it worked! thank you sir ^^